# configure: error: leptonica library missing (when building tesseract-ocr-3.01 on MinGW)

Tags: compilation, mingw, configure, tesseract

When running configure it fails with

```
checking for leptonica... yes
checking for pixCreate in -llept... no
configure: error: leptonica library missing
```

But I have leptonica 1.69 built (downloaded source and ran `./configure && make install`)

---

**Edit**

I think `configure: error: leptonica library missing` is a bit misleading, please note that it first says `checking for leptonica... yes`, and then fails on `checking for pixCreate in -llept... no`. So maybe the problem is not that the library is missing, but something else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally managed to make it compile, after reading [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tesseract-ocr/4infrb1qBLA) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/iulib/issues/detail?id=18) thread. The proper steps for were:

```
./autogen.sh
export LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/local/include
./configure --with-extra-libraries=/local/lib
make install
```

Comment: my paths were `/usr/local/include` and `usr/local/lib` if that helps anyone. Also the second and third line were combined, as per your link.

Comment: This worked for me as well. After installing leptonica from source, had to configure with /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib.

Answer (score 6):

for leptonica 1.69, lib renamed to .libs, so, parameters are

```
export LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=<your_path>/leptonica-1.69/src
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix= --with-extra-libraries=<your_path>/leptonica-1.69/src/.libs
```

and so on

Comment: I used it in ubuntu 14.04 with leptonica-1.73 and it works!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could solve the issue:

```
export LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr-or-other/local/include
```

Comment: Turns out there were some more steps needed (I now posted them in an answer), but still thanks, your advice sent me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 3):

**I am working on redhat linux 7.2 (also applies to RHEL 9)** . None of the solution worked for me 
  I was getting following errors in config.log. 
  *Package lept was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `lept.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable* 
 
 **PKG_CONFIG_PATH** 
configure script uses pkg-config utility to check for packages . 
It was not able to find lept package ( although i had installed leptonica seperately ) 
 By setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH pointing to the directory where lept.pc is present , i was able to resolve the issue .  
 *export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig*

Answer (score 2):

The [FAQ](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/FAQ) addresses this issue and worked for me with tesseract 3.02.02 on Mac OSX 10.6.8.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Leptonica library, png, jpeg, tiff libraries had to passed to the configure script with CXX and  CPP flags. 
To run configure as non-root -
1.  LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=; export LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR; 
2. CXXFLAGS="-ltiff -lpng -ljpeg" CPPFLAGS="-ltiff -lpng -ljpeg" ./configure --prefix= --with-extra-libraries=

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this issue was caused by a missing compiler. Searching `config.log` revealed the following:

`./configure:17287: g++ -o conftest -I/Usr/local/include/leptonica -L/usr/local/lib conftest.cpp -llept >&5
./configure: line 2040: g++ command not found`

Running `apt-get install g++` solved the problem. There is an [issue](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/130) in the tesseract issue tracker about this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (for Ubuntu/Debian) I downloaded the latest leptonica version and the error was not fixed.
To fix it I removed the package "leptonica-dev" with sudo **apt-get remove libleptonica-dev** and then tesseract found the leptonica version installed from the source code.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is going to be slightly different for everyone, depending on the state of your system.

At a high level, the `pkg-config` software needs to know that leptonica is installed. It searches paths for a `.pc` file that has the definition for the leptonica package. That file will be in different locations for different people.

You can find it using the Linux `locate` utility at the command line. `locate lept.pc`. (If you've done some recent installing/uninstalling, you may need to refresh the locate utilities database with the command `updatedb`.)

Whichever directory locate finds the file in, export `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` as that directory (`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` for example).

Then you can continue your configure/build.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem with trying to compile from source, but did not experience it with
apt-get to install tesseract

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

Answer (score -3):

`export LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=$dir/letonica168/include`
`./autogen.sh`
`./configure --prefix=$anotherdir --with-extra-libraries=/$dir/letonica168/lib`
`make`
`make install`