# How to install tesseract in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, tesseract, leptonica

I am trying to use tesserect in cygwin but facing installation issues. I am not good at linux but i know basic commands to get my work done. I used the following link to install the tesserect: [How to build Tesseract on Cygwin](https://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-cygwin.html) but I am stuck at *Installing Tesseract* step **3.Configure it** . On running `./configure LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib` i get the following:

```
Ashok.Sharma.468@CI5W10P051719 /opt/src/tesseract-3.05.01
$ ./configure LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
fatal: Not a git repository: './.git'
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking --enable-graphics argument... yes
checking whether to disable cube... no
checking --enable-embedded argument... no
checking --enable-opencl argument... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking CL/cl.h usability... no
checking CL/cl.h presence... no
checking for CL/cl.h... no
checking OpenCL/cl.h usability... no
checking OpenCL/cl.h presence... no
checking for OpenCL/cl.h... no
checking tiffio.h usability... no
checking tiffio.h presence... no
checking for tiffio.h... no
checking for clGetPlatformIDs in -lOpenCL... no
checking --enable-visibility argument... no
checking --enable-multiple-libraries argument... no
checking whether to use tessdata-prefix... yes
checking whether to enable debugging... no
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 8192
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-cygwin file names to x86_64-unknown-cygwin format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-cygwin file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... file_magic ^x86 archive import|^x86 DLL
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... func_cygming_dll_for_implib
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... Win32 ld.exe
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) supports     shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... Win32 ld.exe
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking if compiling with clang... no
checking whether compiler supports C++11... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for library containing sem_init... none required
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking sys/ipc.h usability... yes
checking sys/ipc.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ipc.h... yes
checking sys/shm.h usability... yes
checking sys/shm.h presence... yes
checking for sys/shm.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking malloc.h usability... yes
checking malloc.h presence... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... no
checking for _Bool... no
checking whether #! works in shell scripts... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for getline... yes
checking for wchar_t... yes
checking for long long int... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for mbstate_t... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for LEPTONICA... no
configure: error: Leptonica 1.74 or higher is required. Try to install libleptonica-dev package.
```

I have already installed leptonica as per the instructions.
I tried [configure: error: leptonica library missing (when building tesseract-ocr-3.01 on MinGW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971253/configure-error-leptonica-library-missing-when-building-tesseract-ocr-3-01-on)
 but in vain. What am I missing?

Comment: leptonica and tesseract are already available as cygwin package, why not use them ?

Comment: @matzeri I didn't know that. Yes it works fine. Thank you.